# Creating choices from admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a school management system with django. I want to add 'staff_type' field in the 'staff' model. On the front end, that will be selected from a dropdown menu. But I don't want to hardcode the choices. I want to add the choices from the admin page. How can I do that with django?

```
from django.db import models

#this is over-simlified.

class person(models.model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length =100)
class staff(person):
    staff_type = models.Charfield(max_length =20)
```

Comment: you can use Enumerations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to add staff types in the admin, you can add another model for that and have a foreign key to that model.

```
class StaffType(person):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Staff(person):
    staff_type = models.ForeignKey(StaffType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Now when you add a `StaffType` in the admin it will be an available choice when you add/edit a `Staff` instance

Answer (score 0):

you can use enums:

```
class staff(person):
    types = (
        (1, "item1"),
        (2, "item2"),
        (3, "item3"),
       )
    staff_type = models.Charfield(max_length =20, choices=types)
```

or you can create ea model and use it in choices,
see below :

```
class TypeList(models.Model):
    type=models.CharField(max_length=15)

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    TypeList=TypeList.objects.all()
    staff_type=models.ForeignKey(TypeList,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). Create a model to store name of staff type. Then create a foreignkey to that model from Staff model.

**models.py**

```
class StaffType(person):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    # other fields


class staff(person):
    staff_type = models.ForeignKey(StaffType, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # other fields
```

Register that model in the admin

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(StaffType)
admin.site.register(staff)
```

When you add a new `staff`, you will get a dropdown for `StaffType` with all the entries of `StaffType` model.